# JSX react/jsx-curly-spacing IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsx

I'm using IDEA 2017.2. I need to setup JSX codestyle so there are spaces between curly braces like `{ event.series }`. However, it autoformats it to `{event.series}`

I have these checked in Javascript -> Spaces.

[image: spaces for objects etc checked]

Where can I set it up so it complies with ESLint's `react/jsx-curly-spacing` set to `"always"`?

---

I have this

[image: I have this]

I want this

[image: I want this]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **2017.2**, it is `Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Spaces`, `Other/Within interpolation expressions`:

[image]

This option affects JSX braces as well as Angular interpolations

Comment: Is there a way to recognize and properly format *double curly* braces too? I.e. it changes `style={{ color: '#ccc' }}` to `style={ {color: '#ccc'} }`...

Comment: do you mean adding a space between `{ {`? No, it's not possible

Comment: No, I mean _not_ adding a space between the braces. Adding a space is what it does. I want the first version of what I posted..

Comment: it doesn't add spaces if `Within interpolation expressions` is not checked.. But this option doesn't currently affect angular interpolations - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31573

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being more explicit - what I'm looking to achieve is both what I said _and_ what the OP wants, i.e.: `eventId={ event.id }` and `style={{ color: '#ccc' }}`
Space within _both single and double braces_,  but _not_ between a double brace.

Answer (score 1):

For **IntelliJ IDEA 2020**, you need to go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript` and in `Spaces` tab find section called `Within`.

If you want to make the below statement look:

```
<div>Hello, ${ to } from ${ from.join( ',' ) }</div>
```

then check the `Interpolation expressions` checkmark.

[image]